# Spring AOP - Pointcut applying to method only when joinPoint.proceed is invoked from a lambda

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

(Title isn't the best, but I couldn't find a good way to phrase the following problem)

Given

```java
@Aspect
@Component
class MyAspect {
  @Autowired private MyService service;

  @Around("@target(org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint)")
  public Object aroundEndpoint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    return service.around(joinPoint::proceed);
  }

  @Around("@target(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)") // And some other expressions to exclude `MyService`
  public Object aroundService(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // ...
  }
}

@Service
class MyService {
  // My own Callable<T> with Throwable instead of Exception
  public Object around(Callable<?> callable) throws Throwable {
    // Do stuff
    Object returnValue = callable.call();
    // Do stuff
    return returnValue;
  }
}
```

When an endpoint method is invoked, it is intercepted by `aroundEndpoint`. If I were to invoke `joinPoint.proceed()` right away, everything would work as expected. However, if I pass it as a method reference (or a lambda) into `MyService.around`, and **then** invoke it, it is matched against my service pointcut and my around service advice is applied to it.

I did some debugging, and here's what I see: in `AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches`, `thisObject` and `targetObject` refer to my endpoint in the former case, but refer to my service in the latter case. This is probably because it uses `ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation()`, and doing another method call messes with it.

Is this a bug? Some limitation of the proxy-based approach? Or do I have to simply inline `MyService.aroundService`?

Comment: Before I look into it, I would like to know why `MyService` is a separate class at all. It seems to specifically cater to the aspect with its `around` method. Is it used outside the aspect too for other purposes? And why do you add extra indirection with method reference or lambda if you could just canonically call `proceed()`? It would be good to see the full picture here, otherwise there is danger that you are stuck in an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898), focusing on the technical solution instead of what you want to achieve. I would like to see the full picture.

Comment: Ideally, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub. That would make it easier for me to reproduce your problem without having to make assumptions when filling in the gaps in the code and speculate about your intent. The question is interesting, I am willing to take a closer look.

Comment: `MyService` doesn't have to be a separate class, I just thought it'd make sense to keep the aspect separate. Same reasoning for the indirection - maybe, sometime in the future, I'd find a better way of hooking into the machinery (unlikely, but still), and `MyService` could remain as it is. I'll be able to provide an MVCE on monday. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @kriegaex https://github.com/moxaj/aspect-mcve. Instructions in the readme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your problem and also compared a similar setup in plain Java + AspectJ (i.e. without Spring or Spring AOP, only using two Spring annotations used in aspect pointcuts). There the problem does not occur. It is something specific to Spring AOP, that much is sure.

Now Spring uses AspectJ's pointcut matching in combination with its own AOP framework based on proxies and delegation. Somewhere in there this edge case must mess up the status of Spring aspect matching, causing the behaviour you see. I have not debugged into it so far, but from what I see now I would suggest to create an issue and see what the maintainers say about it.

Here is my AspectJ [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) proving that the problem does not occur there. BTW, I had to rename the package `aspect` to `aop` because in AspectJ `aspect` is a reserved keyword. But I also renamed it in the Spring project in order to make sure it is unrelated to the problem at hand, and it is unrelated.

```java
package aop.mcve;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {
  public void controllerMethod() {}
}
```

```java
package aop.mcve;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyService {
  public Object delegateTo(MyAspect.Callable<?> callable) throws Throwable {
    return callable.call();
  }

  public void serviceMethod() {}
}
```

```java
package aop.mcve;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  private final MyService myService = new MyService();

  @Pointcut("within(aop.mcve..*) && !within(MyAspect) && execution(* *(..))")
  public void inDomain() {}

  @Pointcut("@target(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)")
  public void inService() {}

  @Pointcut("execution(* aop.mcve.MyService.*(..))")
  public void inMyService() {}

  @Pointcut("@target(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController)")
  public void inController() {}

  @Around("inDomain() && inController()")
  public Object aroundController(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("aroundController -> " + joinPoint);
    return myService.delegateTo(joinPoint::proceed);
  }

  @Around("inDomain() && inService() && !inMyService()")
  public Object aroundService(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("aroundService -> " + joinPoint);
    System.out.println("You should never see this message!");
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }

  public interface Callable<T> {
    T call() throws Throwable;
  }
}
```

```java
package aop.mcve;

public class AspectMcveApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    new MyService().serviceMethod();
    new MyController().controllerMethod();
  }
}
```

The console log:

```
aroundController -> execution(void aop.mcve.MyController.controllerMethod())
```

As you can see, the advice method `aroundService(..)` does not get triggered like in Spring AOP.

---

**Update:** I modified your MCVE in order to make it runnable with both Spring AOP and AspectJ, it automatically detects AspectJ's load-time weaver when active. I sent you this [pull request](https://github.com/moxaj/aspect-mcve/pull/1).

Comment: **Update:** I modified your MCVE in order to make it runnable with both Spring AOP and AspectJ, it automatically detects AspectJ's load-time weaver when active, see my updated answer.

Comment: Merged your pull request. Also, opened [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26068), feel free to chime in if I phrased something incorrectly - I'm kinda new to aspectJ and you are clearly more knowledgeable.